# Reallocate available space from 1 file system to another?

Tags: linux, unix, filesystems, xfs

I am currently using Virtualbox to run this server where my current disk space is:

```
$ df -h
Filesystem                      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/ol-root              50G   44G  6.1G  88% /
devtmpfs                        3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                           4.0G   80K  4.0G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                           4.0G  9.0M  3.9G   1% /run
tmpfs                           4.0G     0  4.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1                       497M  166M  331M  34% /boot
/dev/mapper/ol-home              26G  2.9G   23G  12% /home
```

I would like to increase the `/dev/mapper/ol-root` size by 12gb. I already increased the size of the .vdi file. Then used gparted to allocate the unallocated space.

However all it's done is massively increase my `ol-home` volume with a bunch of unused space. I'd like to move 12gb of that available space to that of `ol-root`.

Can someone explain how to go about doing this and why gparted added the space to `ol-home` instead?

Comment: ol-home is the last partition. Expanding the disk image adds space to the end of the drive, not the start(thats where the MBR is). I'm reasonably sure to shrink/expand the space needs to be contiguous. Google should be able to answer that.

Comment: Thanks for that - I appreciate the explanation!
How would you recommend I go about fixing it? Unmount the bottom 6 FS's and further expand with GParted?

Comment: Long response so I've added it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have a read [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19413/how-can-i-expand-a-partition-into-non-adjacent-free-space-using-gparted).

They're discussing a "real install", because you have a VM you just need to mount the disk image from the HOST OS. Because the guest wont be booted up it allows you full control of the partitions. Remember, backup the disk image before beginning. And if you host OS is windows, you might still want to boot a live USB to have access to GParted, or use another tool.